# Injecting a script to Pod with docker returns EOF

Tags: bash, docker, kubernetes, eof

my goal is to execute a script once on a permanently running pod in kubernetes. The pod is called `busybox-<SOME_ID>` and finds itself in the namespace `default`.Therefore, I wrote this script - called `scan-one-pod.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
export MASTER_IP=192.168.56.102
export SCRIPT_NAME=script.sh
export POD_NAMESPACE=default
export POD_NAME=busybox

echo "echo HALLO" | ssh ubuntu@$MASTER_IP
export POD_ID=$(kubectl get po | grep busybox | sed -n '1p'|awk '{print $1}')
kubectl cp $SCRIPT_NAME $POD_NAMESPACE/$POD_ID:.
kubectl exec  $POD_ID -- chmod +x $SCRIPT_NAME
export CONTAINER_ID=$(kubectl describe pod busybox | grep 'Container ID' | sed -n '1p'|awk '{print $3}')
ssh -t ubuntu@$MASTER_IP "sudo docker exec -u root $CONTAINER_ID -- ./script.sh"
```

The referred script `script.sh` has the following content:

```
$ kubectl exec  $POD_ID --  cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "test" >> test
cp test test-is-working
```

However, it is not possible to run the script on the pod:

- the files `test` and `test-is-working` are not created
- the script `scan-one-pod.sh` returns just `EOF`:

  ```
  $ ./scan-one-pod.sh
  Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
  Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-87-generic x86_64)

   * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
   * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
   * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  155 Software-Pakete können aktualisiert werden.
  72 Aktualisierungen sind Sicherheitsaktualisierungen.


  HALLO
  [sudo] Passwort für ubuntu:
  EOF
  Connection to 192.168.56.102 closed.
  ```
- If I execute the `docker`-command directly, remote on my kubernetes-controller, I get the same message of `EOF`:

  ```
  ubuntu@controller:~$ export CONTAINER_ID=$(kubectl describe pod busybox | grep 'Container ID' | sed -n '1p'|awk '{print $3}')
  ubuntu@controller:~$ sudo docker exec -u root $CONTAINER_ID  ./script.sh
  EOF
  ```
- If I execute it from my local workstation via `kubectl exec` I get this error:

  ```
  $ kubectl exec  $POD_ID  ./script.sh
  rpc error: code = 13 desc = invalid header field value "oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused \"no such file or directory\"\n"
  ```

  I don't know, which missing file they are referring to, but the `script.sh`-file is present and the busybox-pod seems to be running:

  ```
  $ kubectl exec  $POD_ID  ls script.sh
  script.sh

  $ kubectl get po busybox-6bdf9b5bbc-4skds
  NAME                       READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
  busybox-6bdf9b5bbc-4skds   1/1       Running   10         12d
  ```

Question: As far as I know, `EOF` means End-Of-File. End of which file would be important for me to know, and why is that a problem?

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated :)

Comment: One mistake I already found by myself: The image of `busybox` doesn't provide the bash-programm. So I changed the script `script.sh` that I copy to the `busybox`. It now uses `/bin/sh`. BUT: Still `EOF` and the other error posted above with `no such file or directory`.

Comment: `ssh -t ubuntu@$MASTER_IP "sudo docker exec -u root $CONTAINER_ID -- ./script.sh"` you are solving the wrong problem: if the objective is to execute the script, why not use the `kubectl exec` that was _designed_ for that task? Independently, I am about 80% sure that the EOF is caused by `sudo` attempting to ask for a password, but "Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal." prohibits it

Comment: Thank you, the `kubectl exec`-hint solved my problem in deed. Actually, I already had tried that before, but what I did wrong was, that I tried to execute the script with the `./`-command. Correct is: `kubectl exec $POD_ID -- sh script.sh`. Wrong is: `kubectl exec $POD_ID -- ./script.sh`

Comment: If exec requires the `sh script.sh` then it is possible that its [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_\(Unix\)) is invalid, although I readily admit that `./` could be weird based on the current working directory of `exec` (I _think_ it's `/` but that could also be a side-effect of `WORKDIR` in the `Dockerfile`)